# sql select with count in it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql orders table:

```
(id,user_id,skin,item,date,reference,price,to_who)
```

I need to select all users, with sum of orders of lets say 3-7.

that means he has 3 to 7 rows in this DB.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as total FROM orders 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >=3 AND COUNT(*) <= 7
```

Comment: you can use `HAVING total BETWEEN 3 AND 7` instead of counting it multiple times in query.

Answer (score 2):

May be by

```
select * from `orders` group by user_id having count(user_id) between 3 and 7;
```

Comment: -1 This will not work. You are grouping By ID then counting ID, `COUNT(id)` will always be 1. Furthermore, the fact that MySQL accepts `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY x` as valid syntax is a blight on SQL. In this case it will just return 1 random row of `skin,item,date,reference,price,to_who` which is basically meaningless.

Comment: @GarethD No it will not return 1 for every id. It will actually count number of rows. So this is not meaningless. You can try it out. `select my_column,count(my_column) from my_table group by my_column having count(my_column) between 3 and 7;`

Comment: In fairness, I am assuming that ID is a Unique autoincremented field for the orders table when I say it will always be 1 so I could well be wrong. I should have been more clear, I think it needs to be grouped by User_ID to get the number of rows for each user.

Comment: @GarethD Ohh!! O_o. You are right. My bad, I apologize. I meant to use user_id instead of id. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @ypercube There you got it. See I have told you. ;p